# Remote connect to powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to remote connect powershell from windows 7 to windows server 2008 R2 (that's installed in VMware) with ASP.NET.

This is my code :

```
    string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
    var target = new Uri("http://win-qkheb9s51i8/wsman");

    Pipeline p = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
    SecureString passing = new SecureString();
    string password = "A123456a";

    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        passing.AppendChar(c);
    }
    passing.MakeReadOnly();

    var cred = new PSCredential(@"win-qkheb9s51i8\Administrator", passing);

    var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(target, shell, cred);
    connectionInfo.OperationTimeout = 4 * 60 * 1000; // 4 minutes.
    connectionInfo.OpenTimeout = 1 * 60 * 1000;
   runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
   runSpace.Open();
```

but in runSpace.open() sometimes give this error

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
>   Access is denied. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

and sometimes this error:

> ERROR: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the
>   request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is
>   accepting requests.

I read `about_Remote_Troubleshooting` but I can't see why these errors occur. Can anyone help me?

Comment: to troubleshoot... can you even get a connection using Enter-PSession directly from a PS shell?

Comment: hello Juan , yas I can. after this, I call a DHCP Module and the Module returned result from remote machine(windows server).

Comment: edit: now the code give this error: Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: are you running the client & target on the same domain, workgroup, or is only one on the domain?

Comment: yes. I reinstalled IIS of widows server. I obtained this error after running code:The WinRM Client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This usually returned by a HTTP server by a HTTP server that does not support the WS_management protocol. I searched about it and their solution was: Run WinRM quickconfig  in server and in IIS manager in Default website/Edit binding: remove the host name of port 80. I did it but not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you said that both machines are on the SAME domain, but I see you are trying to use the local admin account. That may be an issue but not necessarily. To replicate this, I set up Win2k8R2 on a VM and followed the following steps:

**Steps #1&2 apply to Server 2008 R2 Core Install. If you have the full install, just skip to #3.**

1. Run following commands to Install .NET2 & PowerShell (within cmd.exe)

   - DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /Featurename:NetFx2-ServerCore
   - DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
2. Install some useful PS CmdLets (within cmd.exe)

   - DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename=ServerManager-PSH-Cmdlets
   - DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename=BestPractices-PSH-Cmdlets
3. Enable Remote Shell (within powershell.exe)

   - Set-Excutionpolicy RemoteSigend
   - Configure-SMRemoting.ps1 -force -enable

And then I took your sample code, I didn't really make any substantial changes to it

```
        Console.Write("Target: ");
        var target = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("User: ");
        var user = Console.ReadLine();
        user = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", target, user);
        string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
        var targetWsMan = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:5985/wsman", target));

        using (var passing = new SecureString())
        {
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            var cki = default(ConsoleKeyInfo);
            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
                else
                    passing.AppendChar(cki.KeyChar);
            }
            while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
            passing.MakeReadOnly();

            var cred = new PSCredential(user, passing);

            var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(targetWsMan, shell, cred);
            connectionInfo.OperationTimeout = 4 * 60 * 1000; // 4 minutes.
            connectionInfo.OpenTimeout = 1 * 60 * 1000;
            using (var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                var p = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
                runSpace.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", targetWsMan);
                Console.WriteLine("As {0}", user);
                Console.Write("Command to run: ");
                var cmd = Console.ReadLine();
                p.Commands.Add(cmd);
                var returnValue = p.Invoke();
                foreach (var v in returnValue)
                    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End...");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I did add a dll reference to `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll` just in case its not what you are using.

And then it worked. So my feeling is that its not your code but either your credentials, or the remote setup on the target machine.

Comment: I told yes, because client & server was on the same workgroup WORKGROUP. however I created a domain in my server and joined client to it. but my code give same error. I run all of above cammand in command prompt give error. I dont know what I do. :(

Comment: at which command do you get an error? can you post the error?

Comment: Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name NetFx2-ServerCore is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log  or gives this: Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr
y the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
and another are similar.

Comment: Hello! Finally figured it out. It was the port # in the connection string. add :5985 to it. As far as the setup steps, if you are using server 2008 full install (not core) then skip steps 1&2.