# Are Tasks an appropriate choice when all parallel work units MUST run at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Tasks (the TPL) are the recommended way of performing parallelism since .NET 4.0 as they are a higher abstraction and let the runtime optimise things better.

But in the scenario where all work units *must* happen at once, is TPL still an/the best option?

My use-case is to spawn multiple instances (approximately 10) of PsExec in order to simultaneously run the same process on multiple remote PCs, and wait for each instance to exit. Any 'optimization' by the TPL which resulted in *not* running all instances in parallel would be disastrous.

Does this use-case fall outside the scope of TPL and I'd be better just launching threads?

I'm aware that you cannot execute more threads at once than you have cores but Windows will run more threads than cores by slicing, that is acceptable but scheduling any thread not to run until others have completed is not.

Comment: You can't count on multiple work units run at the same time if you have less CPUs, for example, then number of units. Or some other resources your work units need.

Comment: Are you talking in terms of TPL, or more generally?

Comment: To extend what Spo1ler has said - just because you create, say, 20 threads, the operating system doesn't guarantee that all 20 of those threads will be assigned to a CPU core at any particular point in time. Add in that you're trying to control *remote* resources and at the vagaries of scheduling on that machine as well and network overheads... You need to be a lot clearer on what sort of synchronicity you're actually trying to obtain - is it sufficient if all of the remote processes start within `x` seconds/minutes/hours?

Comment: Generally. If I/O is not involved (some hardware can execute it's I/O inside itself, so it frees the processor) or you don't use something like CUDA, you can't possibly have, say, 10 threads doing some work if you have, say, a 4-core hyperthreading processor. What you can do, is make sure that the work that is needed to run your tasks remotely can execute very fast so that system doesn't need to do many context switches. There is a great chapter on this matter in CLR vis C# by Jeffrey Richter.

Comment: What I'm worried about is a TPL implementation would say "right let's run the first two, then _when those are finished_, do the next two, ..." Whereas a traditional threading implementation would slice things rather than run the threads in series. It doesn't need to be millisecond-accurate :)

Comment: You just can't be sure that system like Windows OS doesn't interrupt your worker threads.

Comment: The [Parallel Extension extras](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4179) contain a `ThreadPerTaskScheduler` that does as the name implies. This way you can still take advantage of tasks, even if you want them to run on threads. (A simpler way is to use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, but that this creates a thread under the covers is an implementation detail -- you should really only use it if your task is actually long running, not just because you want a thread.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thaks for that. I wonder what constitutes "long-running"? It's expected the remote processes will run for minutes or hours though so this probably qualifies. However is it a _guarantee_ this option will do what I need? I'd welcome a full answer on either/both these ideas...

Comment: Is it a guarantee, now and forever, that `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` will put the task on its own thread? No. Is it the case for .NET 4.0 and 4.5? Yes. Beyond that you'll have to use your own judgement. Obviously, `new Thread()` is the only thing absolutely definitely positively guaranteed to run a thread -- but you get none of the convenient synchronization primitives you get with `Task`. On the other hand, you need nothing more complicated than `foreach (t in threads) { t.Join(); }`, so yeah. Nothing in Windows guarantees fairness, so nothing in the TPL can, either.

Comment: *Spawning* a process isn't a long-running task. `Process.Start` returns as soon as the process is started, it doesn't wait for it to finish. How many processes do you need to spawn?

Comment: Also check [this question in serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/626711/how-do-i-run-my-powershell-scripts-in-parallel-without-using-jobs) on how to spawn multiple sessions in parallel using only Powershell.

Comment: Seems [Powershell Workflows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149010.aspx) already allow you to specify remote execution in multiple computers simply by passing the to the `-PSComputerName` parameter

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available

but your scenario,

> "all work units must happen at once"

So there it is, there is no **guarantee** that all process are parallelized. The amount of paralalization will depend on the amount of resources you have (in this case processors/threads) . And even with resources, success will be hinder by the amount of **units** you need to parallelize.

Additionally :

TPL uses threadpools, that means your work is queued to a thread in the threadpoool. But you state

> "but scheduling any thread not to run until others have completed is
>   not"

This could get violate when you have work units more than the available number of threads in threadpool.

Actually my opinion is handling basic threads, would be appropriate for a such a delicate/sensitive task.

Comment: It sounds then like in my case, I don't really have "work units" but am waiting for multiple asynchronous calls to complete... so TPL isn't really the right tool for the job.

Comment: TPL uses threadpools, that means your work is queued to a thread in the threadpoool. But you state "but scheduling any thread not to run until others have completed is not" which could get violate when you have units more than available number of threadpools.. Actually handling low level threads with locks (Most basics things) would be appropriate for a uch a task'

Answer (score 1):

It is at the discretion of the TPL when it starts or tasks code on what thread. If the thread-pool happens to be slow to inject new threads at the moment your tasks can be delayed by many seconds.

By using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` you can make the current versions of the TPL create a new thread for that task immediately. Clearly, you still don't have any guarantees regarding simultaneous execution but it seems approximate simultaneous execution is enough for you.

In my estimation `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is now *guaranteed* to create a new thread in future versions as well for reasons of compatibility. Apps surely have come to rely on various details such as thread ids and thread-local state. This can never be changed (given the history of high-compatibility releases that .NET has).

You should prefer a `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` `Task` over a `Thread` because it composes better with other code and has nicer error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The TPL's behavior isn't really relevant to your scenario - you don't need the TPL to spawn X command-line processes in parallel, you can do it with a simple `for` loop. `Process.Start` doesn't wait for the process to terminate and returns as soon as the process is *spawned*.

The time it takes for `psexec` to connect to a remote machine and spawn a process there is so large that you'll be able to spawn dozens if not hundreds of processes before the first remote machine start to process the request.

If you absolutely must start thousands of processes and the few milliseconds delay of a for loop won't do, you can use `Task.Run(()=>Process.Start...)` to spawn multiple processes in parallel. You'd have to collect the Process objects
returned by all `Task.Run` calls in order to monitor them for completion.

Spawning a process though is a lot more expensive than making the network call directly from your code. You can create remote sessions eg. [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969621/remote-connect-to-powershell-from-c-sharp) and execute pipelines (commands) remotely.

You can use [InvokeAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.invokeasync%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of Invoke to start executing each pipeline asynchronously, either in a for loop or using the TPL. To detect if a command has finished, you need to monitor the pipeline's [PipelineStateInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.pipelinestateinfo(v=vs.85).aspx) property or subscribe to its [StateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.statechanged(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

You can use a TaskCompletionSource to wrap the event and wait on all pipelines for completion.

**EDIT**

Perhaps a better option would be to schedule jobs on the remote computers to run at a specific point in time, by executing [Start-Job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx), rather than trying spawn all the processes at the same time. This avoids a lot of orchestration headaches.

Yet another option is to have Powershell itself [execute the commands in parallel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713710.aspx) using Powershell workflows. Workflows also allow you to execute the same script [on all items in a collection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713711.aspx) in parallel.

**EDIT 2**

Seems Powershell workflows already support spawning scripts on multiple computers simply by using [the PSComputerName parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149010.aspx). Copied from the docs:

```
  The following commands run the Test-Workflow workflow on hundreds
  of computers. The first command gets the computer names from a text
  files and saves them in the $Servers variable on the local computer.

  The second command uses the Using scope modifier to indicate that
  the $Servers variable is defined in the local session.

    PS C:\> $Servers = Get-Content Servers.txt
    PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $ws {Test-Workflow -PSComputerName $Using:Servers }
```